# KML parsing in java

Tags: java, android, parsing, kml

can anyone help me with a simple java code example that shows me how to parse a KML file
this is the file, if anyone would like to have a look at it, I know that I should use the SAXparser but I don't really know how to start.

http://montroyal.googlecode.com/files/SUPreview2.kml

thank you all in advance

Comment: this may help http://mkjparekh.blogspot.in/2011/09/andorid-simple-xml-parsing-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a pretty new thing, there is no best solution apart from using a SAXParser.
If you want something cleaner, try using [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). Note that you'll need to write every models to get it working.

Comment: by the way, I've made a java parser for KML : https://github.com/Ekito/Simple-KML It needs a lot of improvements but it works